# ESLint error for Vue Cli confusion

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I'm using Vue Cli for a project which has an included `.eslintrc.js` which I am trying to stick to. It's finding an error in the code below.

```
getTags (url) {
    axios.get('http://example.test/api' + url).then(response => {
        this.tags = response.data.data
    }).catch(error => {
        this.tags = []
    })
}
```

The exact error is this sections of the code (right after the `.catch`)

```
(error => {
    this.tags = []
    this.loadingTags = false
})
```

The error is `[eslint] Expected error to be handled. (handle-callback-err)`

But I'm confused, as isn't the `.catch(error =>` catching the error? I can't see the problem

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't do anything on the `error` parameter itself ? Try to log it (`console.log(error)`) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something with the `error` parameter, inside your error callback. As the [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/handle-callback-err) says :

> In Node.js, a common pattern for dealing with asynchronous behavior
>   is called the callback pattern. This pattern expects an Error object
>   or null as the first argument of the callback. Forgetting to handle
>   these errors can lead to some really strange behavior in your
>   application.

So you may log it or handle it in a handler you've created :

```
(error => {
    console.log(error)
    // or
    this.handleError(error)

    this.tags = []
    this.loadingTags = false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just don't want to do anything with the error. In those cases you could do this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
(error => {
    this.tags = []
    this.loadingTags = false
})
```

Not to pretty to have these comments in code, but you will get rid of the warnings/errors that you just know are not "real".